# Configuration Files via NPM 'config' package not detected when run as systemd service. (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS)

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, config

I have a simple web application using Node/Express on an Ubuntu (22.04.1 LTS) Virtual Machine.  It uses the NPM package 'config' to fetch environment variables that hold connection parameters for a database.  **When launched from the project root folder via terminal, it runs without issues.**  It successfully connects to mysql, runs the stored procedure and displays the table on the browser.

The web app was developed on windows 10, pushed to a private repo (Ubuntu VM), then pulled onto the VM dedicated to run it.

**The issue arises specifically when it is run as a systemd service.**

The service daemon starts up fine, but gives the warning of:

```
WARNING: No configurations found in configuration folder /home/my_profile/Documents/project_folder/config
```

The client can sent their request to the webapp which then thrown to the index.js route handler, but hits the error due to the previous warning.

```
Error: Configuration property "database.host" is not defined
    at Config.get (/home/my_profile/Documents/project_folder/node_modules/config/lib/config.js:179:11)
    at /home/my_profile/Documents/project_folder/src/routes/index.js:9:22
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/my_profile/Documents/project_folder/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/my_profile/Documents/project_folder/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/my_profile/Documents/project_folder/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/my_profile/Documents/project_folder/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/my_profile/Documents/project_folder/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (/home/my_profile/Documents/project_folder/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
    at next (/home/my_profile/Documents/project_folder/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)
    at Function.handle (/home/my_profile/Documents/project_folder/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:175:3)
```

To me this looks like a permissions or relative pathing issue, but I'm new to systemd. The files contained in the config folders are jsons. Any ideas?

### Pertinent Files

project_webservice.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Node Webserver
Wants=Network.target
After=syslog.target network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/my_profile/Documents/project_folder
ExecStart=/bin/bash ./startWebApp.sh
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const config = require('config');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: config.get('database.host'),
        user: config.get('database.user'),
        port: 3306,
        password: config.get('database.password'),
        database: config.get('database.name')
    });
    let viewData = {};

    connection.connect();
    connection.query("CALL get_summary_since_date('1990-01-01')",  (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) throw error;
        viewData = {
            columns: fields[0],
            rows: results[0]
        };
        res.render('index.ejs', viewData);
    });
    connection.end();
});

module.exports = router;
```

custom-environment-variables.json

```
{
    "database": {
        "host": "DB_HOST",
        "user": "DB_USER",
        "password": "DB_PASSWORD",
        "name": "DB_DATABASE"
    }
}
```

default.json

```
{}
```

## Things I've tried so far:

- I've confirmed the paths and swapped them between absolute and
  relative for the ExecStart property of the .service file.
- Moved the entire folder into the root directory.  Same warning about
  missing configurations but path was auto updated relative to the new
  location.
- Manually set the environment variable "NODE_CONFIG_DIR" as the
  absolute path to that same folder within index.js.  Same behavior.
- Added
  Environment="NODE_CONFIG_DIR=/home/my_profile/Documents/project_folder/config"
  to the service file. Same behavior.
- Gave the config folder full perms for everyone.
- Confirmed env vars were set (redundant as program works when run from
  terminal).
- Added User and Group directives to the service as my user profile.
  confirmed that all associated process ids were under my profile.
- Replacing the config.get() calls with just the hardcoded values, it
  works through systemd.  It's a workaround but not a solution, I should be using environment variables.
- Created a fresh VM install of Ubuntu and tried it again and got the same issue behavior.
- Added other config files as JS modules with the same information.
  same result.

Comment: Is line 9 of your `index.js` just you requiring the config module? Also, what does your `config/default.json` look like? Does it have the correct JSON format to handle `database.host`?

Comment: Line 9 is the first time config.get() is called to retrieve a environment variable.  I assume it does have the correct format as it works fine when the application is launched through the terminal.

Comment: default.json is literally "{}" right now.  Its not being used for anything.  The only data needed is from "custom_environment_variables.json" which is the database.host etc.

Comment: How have you defined the environment variables?

Comment: Yes, they were defined in /etc/environment.  Confirmed assignment in terminal using printenv.